# 'ClassName::class' vs. 'ClassName::class.java' in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

What's the difference between `ExampleClass::class` and `ExampleClass::class.java` in Kotlin?

Comment: @HenryTwist There are great information in the question, you have linked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ExampleClass::class` reference is a value of type KClass. It is specific to Kotlin. Whereas `ExampleClass::class.java` return a Java equivalent of `ExampleClass.getClass()`.

As Kotlin is built on top of JVM, it is interoperable with Java language. So far the sake of interoperability, there are ways to access methods from Java class to Kotlin class and vice-versa. And this is one of it.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Kotlin documentation

::class returns

```
val c = MyClass::class  // reference type of KClass
```

While ::class.java returns

```
val c = MyClass::class.java  // reference type of Java
```

KClass is Kotlin Reflection API, that can handle Kotlin features like properties, data classes etc while JavaClass is in Java reflection api which does not interop with Kotin features.